# Generalised Polya's urn with i.i.d. replacement

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $\mu$ be a fixed measure (possibly with moment conditions) on $\mathbb N$ and $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. samples from $\mu$. Start with one white and one black ball in the urn. At the $n$-th step, a ball is selected from the urn uniformly at random, then we put back the ball with $X_n$ many balls of the same colour.

Let $Z_n$ be the proportion of black balls at the $n$-th step. Then a martingale argument shows that $Z_n \rightarrow Z$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in $L^1$ and a.s.

> Is there any way to relate the distribution of $Z$ to $\mu$?

I have only found generalisations of the urn model where a deterministic number of balls of both colours are put back, depending on the ball drawn (Friedman's urn). Is the urn model described known?